# how to alt click a link using Selenium WebDriver

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

I want to open a link in a new window using the same WebDriver instance. Here is my code so far.

```
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.Keys;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;

public class FirstTest    {

    public void driverIsTheKing()    {

        WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();

        driver.get("http://www.google.com");

        driver.findElement(By.linkText("Gmail")).sendKeys(Keys.ALT,Keys.ENTER);
    }
}
```

This is not working. I need to simulate clicking on the link while holding down the alt or option key. I am running this script on OS X.

Comment: The solution is to use Keys.SHIFT instead of Keys.ALT

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.Keys;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;

public class FirstTest {

    public void driverIsTheKing() {

    WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();

    driver.get("http://www.google.com");

    driver.findElement(By.linkText("Gmail")).sendKeys(Keys.SHIFT,Keys.ENTER);
    }
}
```

Comment: Also, please note that this code works with Selenium Server 2.41.0 but not with 2.40.0

Answer (score 1):

You are close to the answer. Replace Keys.ALT with Keys.CONTROL.

Comment: Well the actual answer is using Keys.SHIFT, but thanks to you for reminding me to try other combinations.

Answer (score 0):

Use Actions Builder in Selenium Webdriver. Example is written below:

```
WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
driver.get("http://www.google.com");
WebElement link = driver.findElement(By.linkText("Gmail"));
Actions builder = new Actions(driver);
Action altClick = builder
          .keyDown(Keys.ALT)
          .click(link)
          .keyUp(Keys.ALT)
          .build();

altClick.perform();
```

Comment: Tried this, did not work on Selenium 2.4.0, Firefox 28, OS X. Is is working for you?

Comment: Did you try with latest webdriver bindings i.e. 2.41.0?

Comment: Yes, I just did and still no luck. The cursor changes from mouse pointer to hand pointer but the new window does not open. Is it running well for you?